# Why does Android's Nexus 7 virtual device not load my "large" layout resources?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support

Using the Nexus 7 in AVD, my `layout-large` resources are not being loaded. I thought that 7-inch devices fell into the "large" category. I have a physical device, the Galaxy 3 Lite, which is 7 inches and loads my "large" resources. I would post some XML, but I feel it should be a straight-forward "7 inches is considered large" issue...  Thanks!

**EDIT:** The expected "large" layout is used in my Genymotion emulator. So why not in the AVD?

Comment: Emulators aren't devices.

Comment: Be that as it may, they are meant to mimic devices and I would expect Android's official Nexus 7 virtual device to load the same layouts as an actual Nexus 7. Are you merely pointing out that this may not be the case?

Comment: It may well not be the case. Even on good hardware with HAXM, x86 image and GPU support, the emulators perform poorly and take up a large portion of the screen. And then you have problems like the one you post. Physical devices pay for themselves in a day or two, and then you have a free second screen. *(note: This is a comment, expresses opinion, and isn't an answer)*

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution exists :

you have to to go in the **AVD Manager** => **Edit** the Nexus 7 Settings => **Show Advanced Settings** => Put the **Custom Skin Definition** to **None**

Then the phone is ugly but the layout-large is used.

And I think the same thing can be applied for other phones that have this bug

Comment: You deserve more upvotes man, I lost way too much time with that issue...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the emulator is completely out of whack. I've used different methods, and the emulator all returns itself as have a "*normal*" class screen. Even though the Virtual Device Manager shows it as a *large* class screen.

Google's Android emulator has always been sub-par, but this is taking it to another level /rant

Comment: After further attempts to troubleshoot, I have the same conclusion. I'm  using Genymotion now with much better results.